# How to get current position of object on canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to create an simple ball game using `Canvas` and `SurfaceView`. I want to move the ball around the screen and for that I have implemented `onTouchEvent()`. I am successfully able to move the ball from anywhere on the screen. But my problem is whenever I touch the screen and starts moving the ball starts moving from the point where I touched the screen.

I want to move the ball from current position. How can I get the current position when start moving?

Here is my `onTouchEvent()`

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int updated_x = (int) event.getX();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                System.out.println("Action Up");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                draw(updated_x);
                System.out.println("Action Move");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

My `draw` method is:

```
private void draw(int updatedValue) {
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), updatedValue, screenY - ball.getBitmap().getHeight() - 260, paint);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
```

and here is my **Ball.java** class:

```
public class Ball {

    private int ball_x, ball_y;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private int minX, maxX;

    public Ball(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_ball);
        maxX = screenX - bitmap.getHeight();
        minX = 0;

    }
```

Comment: u need to get the ``ball`` object current x and y..what is the type of your ``ball`` object?

Comment: something like ``int previous_x = ballObject.getX();``      ``previous_x  = event.getX()``

Comment: I don't get it..will you please elaborate?

Comment: u need to get the ball position first

Comment: Yes that is the question

Comment: your ``ball`` is a ``bitmap``?

Comment: I have added ball class.check the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131879/discussion-between-donald-wu-and-abhaybohra).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `updatedValue` is the absolute position. Instead, this should be a delta value.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int updated_x = (int) event.getX();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            System.out.println("Action Up");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mInitial_x = updated_x;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final int delta_x = mInitial_x - updated_x;
            draw(delta_x);
            System.out.println("Action Move");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the above code, I have made use of a int field `mInitial_x` to keep track of the initial position that you touched. Based on this now you get the delta value of change in x. Use this delta value in your `draw()` method to alter the `ball_x` and then draw.

The key here is not to use the ABSOLUTE value but the RELATIVE value. Hope this helps.